# AWS permanent IP for outgoing requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running AWS EC2 instances with Elastic IPs, and I need to fetch data periodically from 3rd party which is limited to accept connections only from specific IP addresses. I provided them with my elastic address, however after a while the IP that my requests come from to the 3rd party has changed to a completely different one. Is it possible to have permanent IP for outgoing requests on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

If you assign an elastic IP to an EC2 instance, that will be used for outgoing requests.  If you are seeing something different, then there is something wrong.

Are you stopping/starting the instances between requests?  The link between an Elastic IPs and an instance is dropped when the instance is stopped, and will need to be re-assigned after restarting.